# How to compare 2d array with 1 d array?

Tags: java

I am selecting a respective date.  I want to compare 2d array with 1 d array.. but i tried but its not getting for me..

```
 String[] array1= {"06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM","Indiana Fever","Seattle Storm"};

                        System.out.println(array1.length); //3

                        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

                            if(java.util.Arrays.equals(array1, records[i])){

                                WebElement line_up1 = AppSession.findElementByName(game_date);
                                 line_up1.click();
                            }
                        }
```

in my records contains ::

```
06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM
Indiana Fever
Seattle Storm
WNBA
5
07/22/2018 02:00:00 PM
Seattle Storm
Atlanta Dream
WNBA
5
08/01/2018 09:00:00 PM
Phoenix Mercury
Las Vegas Aces
WNBA
5
07/20/2018 06:00:00 PM
Tri-State Tri-State
Ghost Ballers Ghost Ballers
BIG3
5
```

records.length contains 4 and inside 5 column data, like records[0] - 5

Comment: Show in the code where and how records array is defined.

Comment: What are the comparison rules? What is the case to consider two arrays equal?

Comment: Voting for close - questions directed to pure programming should be posted on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Alexey R.  In my gui contains 4 rows and inside row contain 5 column data.. .here I am checking 3 values like gamedate, away team and home team names...which row is matching..then select that row....suppose same date contain 2,3 matches happen, but I need to check with team names, both 3 cases should match then select the game...this is my condition

Comment: @AlexeyR.  but I have a doubt in string records contain same date with same time and different team matches... after checking condition.. the particular match does it will click or not ? here i am mentioning WebElement line_up1 = AppSession.findElementByName(game_date); line_up1.click(); does it will click for that respective game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compare arrays which have different length the comparison will return false. In your case you have `array1->lenght 3` and the specific row in lets say `records[0]-> lengh 5`.
If you remove element "WNBA" and "5" from your records array the comparison is seamless:

```
//      String[][] records = new String[2][3];
//      records[0][0] = "06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM";
//      records[0][1] = "Indiana Fever";
//      records[0][2] = "Seattle Storm";
//      records[1][0] = "06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM";
//      records[1][1] = "Indiana Fever";
//      records[1][2] = "Atlanta Dream";
        String[][] records = {{"06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM", "Indiana Fever","Seattle Storm"},
                {"06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM", "Indiana Fever","Atlanta Dream"}};
        String[] array1 = { "06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM", "Indiana Fever", "Seattle Storm" };

        System.out.println(array1.length); // 3

        System.out.println(records.length); // 2

        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

                System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.equals(array1, records[i]));
        }
```

But if you want to keep your records array intact with 5 element and still want to compare with 3 elements array you can do the following:

```
String[][] records = { { "06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM", "Indiana Fever", "Seattle Storm", "WNBA", "5" },
        { "06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM", "Indiana Fever", "Atlanta Dream", "WNBA", "5" } };
String[] array1 = { "06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM", "Indiana Fever", "Seattle Storm" };

System.out.println(array1.length); // 3

System.out.println(records.length); // 2

for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        if (!array1[j].equals(records[i][j]) {
            System.out.println("not equal");
            break;
        }
        if ((j == array1.length - 1) && (array1[j].equals(records[i][j]))) {
            System.out.println("equal");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me..its working..but I have  a doubt in string records contain same date with same time and different team matches... after checking condition.. the particular match does it will click or not ? here i am mentioning   WebElement line_up1 = AppSession.findElementByName(game_date);
                                 line_up1.click();    does it will click for that respective game?

Comment: Yes the section where you put your click() will be executed only if fist three elements from the corresponding specific row from records array  match the elements in array1. One correction I've made is that was suggested to use equals when comparing elements from both arrays, so I've changed that in my answer. Cheers!